# String manipulation in C#. How to extract a string from a string?

Tags: c#, string

My code:

```
string strFilePath = textBox1.text;
```

The textbox's text typically looks like C:\today\abc def.txt.

I want to isolate 'abc def' into its own string.  That is, everything before '.txt' but after the last '\'.

The string manipulation that I'm familiar with uses Split and Last, but neither are applicable here (I think).

Comment: Actually multiple splits would work fine here.

Comment: Is it `abc def.txt` the name of the file or the folder is called `abc` and the file `def.txt`?

Comment: Shouldn't you use the [standard open file dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`.

Comment: In the current context, this is a bullseye

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was hoping/looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) and [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = @"C:\today\abc def.txt";
string ss = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1, s.IndexOf('.') - s.LastIndexOf('\\') - 1);
Console.WriteLine(ss);
```

Output will be;

```
abc def
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/ocWeZ9)</kbd>.

Or easy way, just use [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

> Returns the file name of the specified path string without the
>   extension.

```
string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"C:\today\abc def.txt");
Console.WriteLine(name); //abc def
```